# Merge two rows - mean if two values or keep data from one row if missing in other

Tags: r

I think title explains everything what I would like to achieve. Data looks like that:

```
aa <- structure(list(`Name` = c("Greg", "Greg"
), Times = c("183538", NA), `Name alternative` = c("Tim", 
                                                            NA), `Comments` = c(NA_character_, "Pierce"), `RECEIVED DATE` = structure(c(1592870400, 
                                                                                                                                                      NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), `Sample No.` = c(12, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                            16), `EXP No.` = c(11, NA_real_), `TYPE` = c(5, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NA)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to merge these rows using column "Name" and keep all of data possible. IF there are two values in the same column mean should be taken.

Comment: What are you grouping your rows by? In general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grouped by `Name` take `mean` of numeric column and the first non-NA value for character columns.

```
library(dplyr)

aa %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm = TRUE), 
            across(where(is.character), ~na.omit(.)[1]))

#  Name  `Sample No.` `EXP No.`  TYPE Times  `Name alternative` Comments
#  <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>              <chr>   
#1 Greg            14        11     5 183538 Tim                Pierce
```

Answer (score 4):

I would throw some `dplyr` at it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) ## for fill
aa %>% group_by(Name) %>%
fill(everything(), .direction='downup') %>%
mutate_if(is.numeric, mean) %>%
distinct
```

This is a rather cheeky way to do it.

Another route, if you could re-insert the non-numeric columns, would be:

```
aa %>% group_by(Name) %>%
summarise_if(is.numeric, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: fill function should be called from tidyr package `tidyr::fill(everything(), .direction='downup')`

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
library(dplyr)
aa %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%  # include if you have different `Name` values
  summarise(across(everything(), 
            ~ifelse(is.na(.), lag(.),.))) %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~mean(.))) %>%
  na.omit()
# A tibble: 1 x 8
# Groups:   Name [1]
  Name  Times  `Name alternative` Comments `RECEIVED DATE` `Sample No.` `EXP No.`  TYPE
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>              <chr>              <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 Greg  183538 Tim                Pierce        1592870400           14        11     5
```